# Codeigniter upload error help me plase

Tags: php, codeigniter

help me plase Codeigniter upload file. My error :

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: getimagesize(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/var/tmp/phpHyN6Ny) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/var/www/vhosts/jizzax.uz/:/tmp/)
>
> Filename: libraries/Upload.php
>
> Line Number: 609

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning

Message: getimagesize(/var/tmp/phpHyN6Ny): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted

Filename: libraries/Upload.php

Line Number: 609
Array ( [error] =>

The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
)
```

Comment: error msg clearly  says "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter's documentation plainly states that you need to define the allowed file types for file uploads. If you don't do this, there is no default list of allowed types.

The relevant code from the documentation can be found below. Specifically, the 'allowed_types' element of the $config array.

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
change to  $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
working code